# Different results with IE and Chrome calculating times with a regex

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm running through a method ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4b6v43mm/)) however results are coming back different in IE and Chrome. In Chrome the seconds are missing! I don't know why the seconds are missing.

Here is the javascript

```js
var array = [];
var times = [];
var d = new Date(0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0);

for (var i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
    array.push(d);
    times.push(d.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3"));

    d = new Date(d.getTime() + 15 * 60 * 1000); // 15 minutes in milliseconds
    console.log(times[i]);
}
```

Comment: First, can you explain what the heck you are trying to do here? This code is all kinds of wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean! When you run through the code and display the output in the cosole you will see that I'm computing an array of times that start at 6am and go to 10PM incrementing every 15 minutes. Ex. 6:00 AM, 6:15 AM, 6:30 AM, etc.

Comment: The problem is when in IE I get 6:00:00 AM and in Chrome I get 6:00 AM. The seconds are missing!

Comment: Use a date handling library (like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)) to do date arithmetic and date formatting and throw away your code. This approach is not worth salvaging.